# Why GridView selection stops working when I disable the horizontal scroll?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

**UPDATE 1**: https://bitbucket.org/vmrocha/gridview-issue/src

**UPDATE 2**: The selection using mouse works, the selection that does not work is the one using touch.

I wrote the following code but, GridView selection stops working when I set the horizontal scrolling to "Disabled".

XAML:

```
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>

    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="itemsPanelTemplate">
        <StackPanel />
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="dataTemplate">
        <Grid Width="100" Height="100">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style TargetType="GridView">
        <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Multiple" />
        <Setter Property="IsItemClickEnabled" Value="True" />
    </Style>

</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <!--The selection here does not work-->
            <GridView x:Name="gridView1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items1}"
                      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource itemsPanelTemplate}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled">
            </GridView>
            <GridView x:Name="gridView2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items2}" Grid.Column="1"
                      ItemsPanel="{StaticResource itemsPanelTemplate}"
                      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}">
            </GridView>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

C# Code:

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.Items1 = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        this.Items2 = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        this.PopulateItems();

        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    private void PopulateItems()
    {
        this.Items1.Add("String 1");
        this.Items1.Add("String 1");
        this.Items1.Add("String 1");
        this.Items1.Add("String 1");
        this.Items1.Add("String 1");
        this.Items1.Add("String 1");
        this.Items1.Add("String 1");

        this.Items2.Add("String 2");
        this.Items2.Add("String 2");
        this.Items2.Add("String 2");
        this.Items2.Add("String 2");
        this.Items2.Add("String 2");
        this.Items2.Add("String 2");
        this.Items2.Add("String 2");
    }
```

If I remove the line ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled", the selection starts working again.

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't regenerate the bug you are telling.

Comment: Did you download the code from https://bitbucket.org/vmrocha/gridview-issue/src and tried to select any "String 1" using touch?

Comment: ok, I got it. It occurs only in touch mode. It seems to be known issues. Have you searched on [MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/windows/apps?query=ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode%3d%22Disabled%22&rq=meta:Search.MSForums.ForumID(04848c5b-0a82-4be1-bab1-eab13c543e5a)+site:microsoft.com&rn=Building+Windows+Store+apps+with+C%23+or+VB++Forum) ?

Comment: The closest question that I found was this (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/b04df2e0-357d-4533-972a-80a5bbcfc4c5), but they did not find a answer as well.

Comment: If you think it is bug in `GridView`, then you should report it to [Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio).